# Joining a 3rd MySQL table (redone)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Okay so I will try to re-explain this question as nobody seemed to understand my aim for this. It's 3am so that's probably where I am slacking a bit... But I'll try my best here.

I am currently working on a Posts & Comments section, users can post on their own or other users walls and as such, other users can comment on those posts. Same kind of thing as a social network status or general forum. I have 3 tables...

```
Users
Statuses
Comments
```

Users contains the standard...

```
userid
username
first_name
last_name
photo
```

Statuses contains any information about a main status posted from each user, these statuses are displayed on the users profiles. So user 1 could post a status on user2's profile. Here is the statuses table design...

```
status_id (auto-i)
user_id (The users ID whos profile the post was added too)
sender_id (The user who sent the post or wrote it)
date (Date/Time was sent)
rate (This doesn't matter for a moment)
comments (This will count all the comments and display the number)
status (The actual status written out)
```

These tables worked fine added together in my script which connected both tables and displayed the users information (the one who posted the status) such as their profile photo and name etc... Here is my current script which has no issues at all...

```
//// GET STATUSES
                                    $user_id = $profile_data['userid'];
                              $data = mysql_query("
                              SELECT 
                     statuses.status_id, 
                     statuses.user_id,
                     statuses.sender_id,
                     statuses.date,
                     statuses.rate,
                     statuses.comments,
                     statuses.status,
                     users.userid, 
                     users.username, 
                     users.first_name, 
                     users.last_name, 
                     users.photo
                              FROM 
                                    statuses
                              LEFT JOIN 
                                    users
                              ON 
                                    statuses.sender_id=users.userid
                              WHERE 
                                    statuses.user_id = '{$profile_data['userid']}' 
                              ORDER BY 
                              `statuses`.`date` DESC
                               ") or die(mysql_error());  

                                  while($status = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))//added this
                                  {
                                  $statusid = $status['status_id'];
                                  $date = $status['date'];
                                  $rate = $status['rate'];
                                  $comments = $status['comments'];
                                  $userid = $status['user_id'];
                                  $senderid = $status['sender_id'];
                                  $statusbody = $status['status'];
                                  $username = $status['username'];
                                  $firstname = $status['first_name'];
                                  $lastname = $status['last_name'];
                                  $photo = $status['photo'];

                                  ?>
<form action="" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="statusupdate" class="facebook-share-box">
            <div class="share">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading"><a href="<? echo 'http://basecentre.co.uk/',$status["username"]; ?>"><img alt="" align="left" hspace="20" height="70" width="70" src="<? echo 'http://basecentre.co.uk/userimages/',$status["photo"]; ?>"> </a> <font size="+2"><i class="icon icon-comment-o"></i></font> <a href="<? echo 'http://basecentre.co.uk/',$status["username"]; ?>"><font size="+2"><?php echo $status['first_name']; ?> <?php echo $status['last_name'] ; ?></font></a> | <i class="icon icon-clock-o"></i> <a rel="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="<? echo "". date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($status['date']) + 60*60) .""; ?>"><?php echo "<strong>". date('j F', strtotime($status['date']) + 60*60) ."</strong>"; ?></a></div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="">
                            <?php echo $status['status']; ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                Comment | Like
                                </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
                               </br>


<? 
                                  }


    ?>
```

I have built a new table for the comments. So I could go to a users profile, read a "status" and then I could add a comment to it... Here is that new table...

```
comment_id (auto-i)
status_id (added depending on which status you comment on. If the comment is on status id #5, the same number will be sent to this to connect the comments with the correct statuses)
sender_id (the id of the user who is sending the comment which would be $_session['userid'];
date (date the comment was sent)
rate (Doesn't matter yet)
comment (the actual comment written out).
```

I need to join the new comments table to the other two tables, somehow? I tried adding another "left join" but that didn't work? And I'm not too good with this stuff.
My aim is to get each comment correctly displaying on its connected status, in order of the date posted. Most recent at the bottom... With the users info showing so you know who has posted the comment.

Hope this gives you a bit more understanding and I hope someone can help!! Sorry it's pretty long but you guys asked for a bit more info... Thanks!

Edit add database records:

statuses table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statuses` (
  `status_id` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `rate` int(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comments` int(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`status_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=30 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `statuses`
--

INSERT INTO `statuses` (`status_id`, `user_id`, `sender_id`, `date`, `rate`, `comments`, `status`) VALUES
(15, 11, 22, '2014-05-11 21:22:00', 0, 0, 'This is pretty damn cool! '),
(16, 11, 91, '2014-05-11 21:22:35', 0, 0, 'LOL how did you do this shit man?? Alll you gotta do now is add the comments ;) and likes! '),
(14, 11, 22, '2014-05-11 21:21:35', 0, 0, 'Hey budddy how are ya ? '),
(13, 11, 11, '2014-05-11 21:18:10', 0, 0, 'eerer'),
(11, 11, 11, '2014-05-11 21:10:33', 0, 0, 'Ho Ho!'),
(10, 11, 11, '2014-05-11 21:10:27', 0, 0, 'Hey hey ! '),
(28, 11, 11, '2014-05-12 00:47:02', 0, 0, 'LOL just another quick test ;) '),
(29, 22, 22, '2014-05-12 02:30:44', 0, 0, 'I should be able to delete this status... '),
(20, 11, 11, '2014-05-11 21:30:17', 0, 0, 'LOL WINNER'),
(21, 22, 11, '2014-05-11 23:31:18', 0, 0, 'Hey mate :D '),

(19, 11, 11, '2014-05-11 21:24:47', 0, 0, 'Not bad eh guys? ;P ');
```

Comments table:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `comments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `comment_id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status_id` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `rate` int(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `comments`
--

INSERT INTO `comments` (`comment_id`, `status_id`, `user_id`, `sender_id`, `date`, `rate`, `comment`) VALUES
(1, 28, 11, 11, '2014-05-12 01:23:58', 0, 'Hmmm shall we see if we can get this working too!? Comments, here we come! '),
(2, 28, 11, 22, '2014-05-12 02:55:33', 0, 'This is not aidans comment! another username should appear!');
```

Users table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userid` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default.png',
  `date1` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `date2` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `date3` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `birthplace` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `about` varchar(250) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'This information has not yet been updated.',
  `user_level` enum('0','1','2','3','4') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `signup_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `activated` enum('0','1') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `location` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `premium` enum('0','1') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `blocked` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fr_alert` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `um_alert` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci COMMENT='Membership Information' AUTO_INCREMENT=92 ;
```

Comment: do you want only posts that have a comment to show up? or do you want there to be some without comments?

Comment: We need to see your current query

Comment: I want all posts to show either with or without comments.

Comment: My current query is in the post

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this? not exactly sure what your data looks like so it could be wrong.. join on the user that sent the comment and the status id and then order by comment DATE desc then status DATE desc so it'll give the most recent comments by the most recent posts

```
SELECT -- added alias to your tables so its easier to read
    s.status_id, 
    s.user_id,
    s.sender_id,
    s.date,
    s.rate,
    s.comments as s_comment,
    s.status,
    u.userid as u_id, 
    u.username as u_name, 
    u.first_name as u_first, 
    u.last_name as u_last, 
    u.photo as u_photo,
    o.userid as o_id, 
    o.username as o_name, 
    o.first_name as o_first, 
    o.last_name as o_last, 
    o.photo as o_photo,
    c.comment as c_comment
FROM statuses s
LEFT JOIN users u ON s.sender_id=u.userid
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.user_id = u.userid AND c.status_id = s.status_id
LEFT JOIN users o on o.userid = c.sender_id
WHERE s.user_id = '{$profile_data['userid']}' 
ORDER BY c.date DESC, s.date DESC
```

give it a try and let me know what any issues are.. also if you could edit your post with a few lines of the actual data like some of the comments with a few posts and status and like one dummy user i can test this myself and clarify (would be LOADS easier)

Comment: I am getting an error saying "Not unique table/alias: 'o'" Is this because users o is the same as 'u'?

Comment: try again with alias for each table name.. i think it was trying to combine like columns (with the same column name)

Comment: It's working apart from it's showing all posts on everybody's profiles? And where the comments are both meant to be on that one status, its showing the status twice with a different comment on each?

Comment: the where clause should be filtering out other users.. i made another edit for you to try.. i wrote it to show a different row for each comment... did you want a new column for each of the comments with the users name and id and stuff? because to do that you have to manually write in each column in your select.

Comment: from here all you have to do is take the  data.. loop through it and if the status id is the same for multiple rows pull out the comments and add to one status row... that is the best way to do this

Comment: you also may need to change the `LEFT JOIN users o` to `INNER JOIN users o` as that may be whats causing you to see all users ---- but i just tested with my sqlfiddle and it seems to be filtering out other users

Comment: The original code that I posted displayed the statuses that statuses.user_id matched the profiles information $profile_data['userid'] so that only those statuses where you're userid are entered into the statuses.userid would show. It shown the users first name and last name picked from the entry in statuses.sender_id. It seems to work fine in that sqlfiddle so I don't know why I can't seem to get it working on the site :/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/145db/3  it may be because youre putting the wrong name in there.. meaning that you are putting in the sender name instead of the user name? make sure you clarify.. because on my end its working fine as you just said :)

Comment: This is perfect! Works!! I am still getting the status with the two comments appearing twice though? One time for each comment? Where both comments should be on the same status?

Comment: yea so the way you have it set up now will do that... all you need to do is a for loop in the results (before putting in html) and if the status_id is the same for more than one row you need to add the comments together.

Comment: basically make an array with all of the data from the sql select in that while loop... then loop through that array with an if to check the status_id.. append that into another array (so you filter out the additional status) and then get your info from that array to put on the html page. to do this in sql is next to impossible

Comment: How do I check if the status_id is the same for more than one row? Do I need to check it against the comments database?

Comment: Okay I'll give this a try, thank you so much for your help tonight, really appreciate it!

Comment: no just inside the results from your query.. if there is more than one row with the same status id then get the comments from that row and add it to the previous row. its ordered by id so itll be in order (next to eachother)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145607/php-check-if-an-array-has-duplicates ----- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170807/how-to-detect-duplicate-values-in-php-array ---- those two links may help you understand how to find duplicates.. once you find them then just put the comment with the user name into an array then add to other array with total unique data :D

Comment: How would I add it to the previous row? Would I do that using an = statement?

Comment: well im not very good with php.. im more a python guy myself :) but basically your logic would be like this if ( $status_id in set //(there should be a `set` in php.. there is in python. its a set of values for it to compare with) $name = $username; $comment = $c_comment;) then loop through your other array youre making to be the final array, find the id that matches and add those additional items to that row

Answer (score 1):

This answer slightly changes some of the table structure but the core ideas behind it are the same.

Using the example I've created here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1fa6e/1

So basically you can INNER JOIN (results from both tables) the `status` table, against the `users` table twice, and use the `AS` operator to create alias names for them. This lets you join users against it to get the profile owners information, as well as the information of the person posting the status. (The example below shows only status that are posted on profile owner #1)

```
SELECT status.status_id, 
  profile_owner.username AS owner, 
  status_sender.username AS sender
  FROM status
  INNER JOIN users AS profile_owner
    ON profile_owner.user_id = status.user_id
  INNER JOIN users AS status_sender
    ON status_sender.user_id = status.sender_id
  WHERE profile_owner.user_id = 1;
```

Result

```
STATUS_ID OWNER     SENDER
1         User 1    User 2
2         User 1    User 4
```

To then add comments, you `LEFT JOIN` the comments table (there may not always be comments, in which case these fields will be null), then to get the user details of the commentor we `INNER JOIN` again the user table, against the commentors ID to get their details

```
SELECT status.status_id, 
  profile_owner.username AS owner, 
  status_sender.username AS sender,
  status.status,
  status_comment.comment_body,
  commentor.username AS commentor
  FROM status
  INNER JOIN users AS profile_owner
    ON profile_owner.user_id = status.user_id
  INNER JOIN users AS status_sender
    ON status_sender.user_id = status.sender_id
  LEFT JOIN status_comment
    ON status.status_id = status_comment.status_id
  LEFT JOIN users AS commentor
    ON status_comment.commentor_id = commentor.user_id
  WHERE profile_owner.user_id = 1;
```

Giving these results

```
STATUS_ID OWNER    SENDER  STATUS                         COMMENT_BODY                          COMMENTOR
1         User 1   User 2  Test status on User1 by User2  User3 commenting on status by User2.  User 3
1         User 1   User 2  Test status on User1 by User2  User4 commenting on status by User2.  User 4
2         User 1   User 4  Test status on User1 by User4  (null)  (null)
```

This shows User1 has 2 status posted on their profile, one was by User2 and had 2 comments, the other was by User4 and has no comments. You can then parse these results in PHP and display appropriately.

Once you break it down, it's fairly straight forward.

You can [view it all in action here and play with it yourself on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1fa6e/1).

**Update:** Using the database information you edited into your post, [I have created an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78e8d/1) to attempt to show you how to apply this to your existing database.

It was quite straight forward, you just seemed to have translated my example to your code slightly wrong. Below is the correct query with the appropriate table names changed.

```
SELECT statuses.status_id, 
  profile_owner.first_name AS owner, 
  status_sender.first_name AS sender,
  statuses.status,
  comments.comment,
  commentor.first_name AS commentor
  FROM statuses
  INNER JOIN users AS profile_owner
    ON profile_owner.userid = statuses.user_id
  INNER JOIN users AS status_sender
    ON status_sender.userid = statuses.sender_id
  LEFT JOIN comments
    ON statuses.status_id = comments.status_id
  LEFT JOIN users AS commentor
    ON comments.sender_id = commentor.userid
  WHERE profile_owner.userid = 11;
```

This pulls all the statuses posted on the profile of user id 11. It also pulls any comments those status may have.

**On a side note...**I'm unsure why you're storing the `sender_id` and `user_id` in the `comments` table. Your comment is already related to a status, so you know whom it's posted against, you only need to store who is making the comment.

Try to think of each entity as it's own object.

You have 3 objects

- User
- Status
- Comment

A status has a user who it's posted against (`status.user_id`), and the user who posted it (`status.sender_id`).

A comment has a status it's posted against (`comments.status_id`), and the user who posted it (`comments.sender_id`).

There is no need to store the `status.userid` again in the comments table, as you can always join it to get that information.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is the kind of thing I was looking for to give me a better understanding of joining tables! Although, in my original query I had the variables listed from the query, (i.e: statuses.status_id, statuses.user_id, users.userid, users.photo etc...) where would I incorporate this into your query to use the variables back as "$status['photo']" or whatever?

Comment: In a `SELECT` statement, you define which columns you want to have returned as part of your query. In our example though because we have fields named the same thing (such as the `username`s) I have used the `AS` alias operator to essentially rename that column in the resultset. So to pull the `photo` column for the profile user, you add something like this to your select: `profile_owner.photo AS profile_owner_photo` and then you can use `$status['profile_owner_photo']`

Comment: I've just tested it out and have an error saying "Table 'u634727706_bc.status_comment' doesn't exist" Not sure why because they both exist?

Comment: Can you paste the code you used to test it along with the full error message to something like http://pastebin.com/

Comment: The full error message is what I've written above, that is all it said.

Comment: You're getting that because you're tryingto join to a table named `status_comment`, but in your schema I just saw you posted above, that table is named `comments`. I'll create a fiddle with the schema/data you posted above and show you how the queries should look.

Comment: Okay, I'll change it now and give that a go.

Comment: @Jessiikah1992 Updated with an sqlfiddle of the query translated properly, you had just missed a table name or two.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how SQL is retrieving the results for you. You need to loop over the results you get on your page and group them logically. The reason a status with 8 comments will appear 8 times in your existing code is because there will be 8 rows associated with that status. One for each comment. So you can check for the status_id as you're looping, and only display a new status on your page each time it changes. Run the SQLFiddle links I posted and you'll see why.

Comment: Is there a way I can stop this from happening ? Without messing up the query?

Comment: This is how it's supposed to work and it's the more efficient way of processing you data. You just need to learn to work with it as I've been explaining to you (and so has @JohnRuddell too by the look of it).

Comment: Okay no worries, thanks so much for helping me out with this today, I really appreciate it! Couldn't have done it alone!