# Find Equal Array php

Tags: php, arrays

i have associate array like this :

```
$json_data = array();
$jason_data[]= array ('id'=>'1','brand'=>'chanel','name'=>'red');
$jason_data[]= array ('id'=>'3','brand'=>'lacoste','name'=>'green');
$jason_data[]= array ('id'=>'1','brand'=>'chanel','name'=>'red');
```

`$jason_data[0]` and `$jason_data[2]` are Equal

i want find in `$jason_data` for equal array and echo them

Comment: And what have you  tried, to accomplish this goal?

Comment: `$json_data` **is not the same as** `$jason_data`

Comment: Do a foreach and compare each key, write it as a function

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: check if an array has duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145607/php-check-if-an-array-has-duplicates)

Comment: Just do `array_pop($jason_data);` then check it using `var_dump($jason_data);` you will get the equal arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whats the context of this and your question is vague, but anyway, I hope this is what you want to achieve. (and your variable naming is odd). In your example index zero and two are the same, and since they are multi-dimensional, you can flatten them in a way by using `serialize`. Try this:

```
$json_data = array();
$json_data[]= array ('id'=>'1','brand'=>'chanel','name'=>'red');
$json_data[]= array ('id'=>'3','brand'=>'lacoste','name'=>'green');
$json_data[]= array ('id'=>'1','brand'=>'chanel','name'=>'red');

$json_data = array_map('serialize', $json_data);
$values = array_count_values($json_data);

echo '<pre>';
foreach($values as $array => $count) {
    if($count > 1) {
        $array = unserialize($array);
        print_r($array);
    }
}
```

Should output/print the ones that has duplicates:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [brand] => chanel
    [name] => red
)
```