# How to check duplicate results of a random character generator

Tags: php

I have made a random character generator, but how do I check if an result is duplicate?
E.g., if I want 100000 results, how do I check if an result is not duplicate in the 100000 results?

```
for ($i=0; $i<$quantity; $i++){
$a = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
$b = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
$c = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
$d = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
$code = "$a-$b-$c-$d";
echo $code .'<br>';
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removed the run snippet markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe? Using in_array()

```
$previous = array();

for ($i=0; $i<$quantity; $i++){
    $unique_found = false;
    while(!$unique_found){
        $a = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
        $b = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
        $c = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
        $d = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);

        $code = "$a-$b-$c-$d";

        if(!in_array($code,$previous)){
            $unique_found = true;
            $previous[] = $code;
            echo $code .'<br>';
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you'll want to do is save all the codes you generated into an array.

```php
$codes = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$quantity; $i++){
    $a = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
    $b = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
    $c = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
    $d = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
    $code = "$a-$b-$c-$d";
    echo $code .'<br>';
    $codes[] = $code;
}
```

To check if it contains duplicates, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145607/php-check-if-an-array-has-duplicates) proposes the following solution:

```
if (count($codes) == count(array_unique($codes))) {
    // array contains duplicates
}
```

If you're interested in which code exactly is a duplicate, try this instead. I'm sorting the array first (to make sure equal values are consecutive), and then checking if two consecutive values are equal.

```
sort($codes);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($codes) - 2; $i++) {
    if ($codes[$i] == $codes[$i + 1]) {
        // $codes[$i] is a duplicate
    }
}
```

And if you're implying you want to get rid of duplicates, then it's as simple as using `array_unique`:

```
$codes = array_unique($codes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myValues = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$quantity; (if($unique){$i++;})){
 $a = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
 $b = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
 $c = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
 $d = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
 $code = "$a-$b-$c-$d";
 $unique = false;
 if(!in_array($code,$myValues)){
   $myValues[] = $code;
   echo $code .'<br>';
   $unique = true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code as key in an array, so repeated ones will be overwritten:

```
$results = array();
$quantity = 10000;
    while (count($results) < $quantity) {
       $a = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
       $b = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
       $c = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
       $d = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);

       $code = "$a-$b-$c-$d";
       $results[$code] = $code;

    }
```