# Show only duplicate elements from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an sorted array which contains first names of people.
This array has lots of names which are same.

I want to output only duplicate names.

Example,

input array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Abbas
    [1] => Abhay
    [2] => Abhinav
    [3] => Abhishek
    [4] => Aditya
    [5] => Ahmed
    [6] => Ahmed
    [7] => Ajay
    [8] => Ajay
}
```

It should return

```
Array
(
    [5] => Ahmed
    [6] => Ahmed
    [7] => Ajay
    [8] => Ajay
}
```

Comment: you want to look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170807/how-to-detect-duplicate-values-in-php-array

Comment: Do you need to preserve the original index numbers?

Comment: @nobita That could help. But it only returns the number of time an value occured. Actually, is there any way to get keys of values which occurs more than once?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this code:

```
# assuming your original array is $arr
array_unique(array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr)));
```

It will return **unique duplicates** but if you want **non-unique duplicates** then use:

```
array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr));
```

#### EDIT: Based on your comments, try this code:

```
$uarr = array_unique($arr);
var_dump(array_diff($arr, array_diff($uarr, array_diff_assoc($arr, $uarr))));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
array(4) {
  [5]=>
  string(5) "Ahmed"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "Ahmed"
  [7]=>
  string(4) "Ajay"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "Ajay"
}
```

Comment: I tried array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr));
but it only returned element 6 and 8 from the example above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php to get an array withoutt he duplicate values, then you can use this function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php to find the differences, maintaining key association.

Comment: I think this seems like the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Try array_reduce:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Create a callback that populates an array using the values from $input as keys, and increments them accordingly. And then filter those that appear more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_count_values()` to count up everything in the array, then filter the resulting array to show only the ones where there's more than 1:

```
$input = array(.... your names here ....);

$counts = array_count_values($input);

$duplicates = array_filter($counts, function element { return ($element > 1) });
```

Doing that off the top of my head, but should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Is there any way to know the keys whose values occured more than once?

Comment: $counts would have a set of `name => count` values in it. just look for the elements where count > 1, which is what the array_filter does.