# Detect Array duplicate on PHP

Tags: php

i want to print array duplicate, example :

```
$input = ['a', 'a', 'b'];
$output = array_unique($input);
echo $output;
```

i run code in php online ,but output just like this..

```
Array
```

how to echo "A" because "A" is duplicate alphabet from array above ?

Comment: There are several ways.  But I'm not sure what you want.  Basically you want to display all the dups?  What if it is [a,a,b,b,c]?  What will you display?

Comment: Check this _—>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995095/show-only-duplicate-elements-from-an-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show only duplicate elements from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995095/show-only-duplicate-elements-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, you just cannot print an entire array with 'echo' statements. As written, you can print individual elements of $output (for example  echo $output[0]; or echo $output[1];). If you want to print the whole array, use print_r($output); or var_dump($output);

Answer (score 0):

Array_unique will not give you that information, it will only delete the duplicates.
If you count the values with array_count_values then use array_diff to get what is **not** 1, then the code will return the duplicated items.
But it will return them in keys, so use array_keys to get them as values.

```
$input = ['a', 'a', 'b'];
$count = array_count_values($input);
$duplicated = array_keys(array_diff($count, [1]));
var_export($duplicated);
```

https://3v4l.org/2HS8e

You can also echo the duplicates with:

```
echo implode(", ", $duplicated);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array_diff` or `array_diff_assoc` for compute two array. (before and after doing remove duplicate by using `array_unique`)

Example :

```
$array = ['a','b','c'];
$array2 = $array;

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($array);
echo "</pre>";

$array = array_unique($array);
$diff = array_diff_assoc($array2,$array);

echo '<hr>Diff : ';
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($diff);
echo "</pre>";
exit();
```

See the result here.

[image]

Comment: Avoid posting code (and output) as images, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question