# Simple way to identify repeated strings in an array? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array with values $somearray = array('car','bike','legs,'car'). I'd like to find out which of these values in $somearray are repeated and pick out the index. In this example the answer would be 'car' and the index of the array would be 0 and 3.

I'm wondering if this can be done simply in a few lines, perhaps using some PHP function that I don't know, or do I need to explicitly make comparison in nested loops?

TIA!

Comment: (Array) functions you might not know can be looked up here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple and I bet you can write it yourself. All you need is just 2 functions: [array_count_values()](http://php.net/array_count_values) and [array_keys()](http://php.net/array_keys) with specified second argument (thanks to @prodigitalson)

Answer (score 0):

There's a good answer on this similar question - [How to detect duplicate values in PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170807/how-to-detect-duplicate-values-in-php-array)

To get the array indexes, I would then filter any array value > 1 and get the indexes