# preg_match all words in a string

Tags: php, preg-match

Looking fo possibility to detect if `$string` is match all words in `$array`.
Words order not known in advance (user typed text).

```
array(
  'test',
  'shmest',
  'zest',
  'fest',
  'etcest'
);
```

I undertand that i can:

```
$is_match = true;
foreach ($array as $word) {
  if (!strpos($string, $word) === false) {
    $is_match = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

(Can|Should) i make somethin like above via preg_match[_all]?

**EDIT1**

Priority is less memory and fast work.

Tested 2 unswers and own above
https://eval.in/144266
so my is fastest

And `$string` can contain of any symbols

Comment: What is your input and what will be the match ?

Comment: check if it helps you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575899/php-in-array-find-any-matches

Comment: input somthing like: 'lets zest from the test and shmest of the etcest like fest' - should be true. if one of the words a missing in the string - false

Comment: @www.sblog.in nope. I`m not looking word `in_array` but all words in array exists in the string

Comment: Quote [from the PHP website](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php): `Tip:
Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.`

Comment: I have my doubts as to whether anything involving PCRE would be faster or more memory efficient. For a very large haystack and/or a very large number of needles it *might* be faster (especially when the same regex is used repeatedly in a single script), but it certainly won't be more memory efficient. To improve on what you have you probably want to be looking at some kind of hybrid boyer-moore algorithm that can handle multiple needles - which is unlikely to make a difference when implemented in userland PHP. Either way, I suspect this is a micro-optimisation (borne out by your test results).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a RegEx with LookAheads:

```
$regex='/(?=.*?'.implode(')(?=.*?', $needles).')/s';
```

then simple check against your string:

```
if (preg_match($regex,$string)===1) echo 'true';
```

Demo code: https://eval.in/144296
Explained RegEx: http://regex101.com/r/eQ0hU4

Comment: Great answer, but it returns `true` when `$needles` has a word that's is not presented in `$string`

Comment: @elDude unable to replicate your exception, can you drop by in [regex room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex-regular-expressions) to clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) and [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

```
$words = preg_split("/(?<=\w)\b\s*/", $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo (array_intersect($arr, $words) == $arr) ? 'True' : 'False';
```

Basically `preg_split()` splits your input string into an array of words. `array_intersect()` checks if all the elements in `$arr` are present in `$words`.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/144192)

Comment: this works. but if going further and if $input not only [a-zA-Z\s], something like '* 1.0 /\'?

Comment: @Subdigger: What do you mean by `'* 1.0 /\'`?