# php check array value for duplicate

Tags: php, arrays

i have this below array:

**PHP**

```
$arr=array('A','A','B','C');
```

i want to check value and if values are duplicate must be alert error

**PHP**

```
$chk=array_count_values($array);
if ( $chk[0] < 1 || $chk[2] < 1 || $chk[3] < 1  || $chk[4] < 1 )
    echo 'array must be uniq';
```

Comment: Check the first "Related" link to the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170807/how-to-detect-duplicate-values-in-php-array?rq=1 .. If one of the values (see the accepted answer) > 0.. you have a duplicate..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [`array_unique()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), this can be easily refactored into a new function:

```
function array_is_unique($array) {
   return array_unique($array) == $array;
}
```

Example:

```
$array = array("a", "a", "b", "c");
echo array_is_unique($array) ? "unique" : "non-unique"; //"non-unique"
```

Comment: For PHP >= 5.1, may I suggest array type hint:
function array_is_unique(array $array) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$arr  =   array('A','A','B','C');
if(count($arr) != count(array_unique($arr))){
  echo "array must be uniq";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
if ( count($arr) != count(array_unique($arr)) ) {
  echo 'array must be uniq';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could walk thhrough it with a foreach loop and then use the strpos function to see if a string contains duplicates

Answer (score 0):

From [Php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

> array **array_unique** ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
>
> Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.