# How to check if an array has a value multiple times

Tags: php, arrays

I want to see if an array has the same value multiple times,example:

```
$array=array('val1','val2','val3','val1');
```

As you can see,in the array above, there are 2 x val1 .
To search if an array contains a value,i can do it with in_array:

```
$search=in_array('val1',$array);
```

And it will return true because val1 exists in array,but i need to return true if the value is found multiple times.

Comment: [array_count_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: The array_count_values() function counts all the values of an array. I want only to see if a value has duplicates in array.

Comment: RTFM: array_count_values() returns an array using the values of array as keys __and their frequency__ in array as values

Comment: array_count_values() would return `val1 => 2`, this would indicate that are are 2 instances of `val1`, therefore, there's a duplicate.

Comment: `$search = (array_count_values($array)['val1'] > 1);`

Comment: aham,well i will try it,and return with an answer

Comment: This may help you! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170807/how-to-detect-duplicate-values-in-php-array)

Comment: array_count_values($array)['val1']  this syntax gives me some errors....my editor show that this syntax isnt correct

Comment: Your editor is not correct..... that code is valid from PHP 5.4.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can exploit a lesser known feature of `array_keys()`, which is used to return the keys of an array as a new array (i.e. without values.)

It accepts an optional second parameter, `search`, that allows you to stipulate that you wish to have only those keys returned whose value corresponds to your search. So:

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'one', 'three');
$indexes = array_keys($arr, 'one'); //array(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

By providing the search_value as second parameter to array_keys. The function will return only the keys of the array containing the value.

```
$array=array('val1','val2','val3','val1');
$search = array_keys($array, 'val1');
```

For reference, **[Please READ](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)**

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<?php
$array = array('val1','val2','val3','val1');
$cnt = array_count_values($array);
echo $cnt['val1'];
```

https://eval.in/202593

Comment: your suggestion it's awesome,but i have a question if the value that im searching , is actualy a $_POST['val1'] , how should i build the syntax? $cnt($_POST['val1']) it's good?

Comment: $_POST is array, try array_count_values($_POST)['val1'];

Comment: if array('val1','val2','val3','val1'). in $_POST['val'] u will send something like 'val1'?

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick:

```
function check_multi($testVal,$arr) {
   foreach($arr as $curVal) {
     $counts[$curVal]++;
   }
   if(isset($counts[$val])
     return $counts[$val];
   else
     return null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

https://eval.in/202596

```
echo array_count_values($array)["val1"];
```

You will get the following array when you execute [this](https://eval.in/202598)

Comment: are you sure this syntax is correct? i get some syntax errors in my editor

Comment: @Petru - what version of PHP are you using? This is array dereferencing, which was introduced in PHP 5.4.0

Comment: @PetruLebada Try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php#refsect1-function.array-count-values-examples) You will understand.