# How do I find duplicates in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there anyway to find duplicates in array values? like:-

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "BMW", "Toyota");
```

As **BMW** and **Toyota** occurs twice output would be **BMW** and **Toyota**
i know about array_search() but in that you have to provide what you want to search..
i can match array value with respect to key but size of array can vary, It would be great if anyone help me out.

Comment: What do you mean "match values"? Are you asking "How do I find duplicates in a PHP array?"

Comment: @tadman  yes i want to find duplicates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect duplicate values in PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170807/how-to-detect-duplicate-values-in-php-array)

Comment: Lots of ways to end up with an array of unique items... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Related: [Specific results for returning array duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54655159/2943403)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is using `array_count_values()` and include only array elements with more than one values.

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "BMW", "Toyota");

foreach( array_count_values($cars) as $key => $val ) {
    if ( $val > 1 ) $result[] = $key;   //Push the key to the array sice the value is more than 1
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => BMW
    [1] => Toyota
)
```

Doc: [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
function array_match_dump($array){
   return array_unique(array_diff_assoc($array,array_unique($array)));
}
```