# Specific results for returning array duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I checked other similar questions like  [php check array value for duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219100/php-check-array-value-for-duplicate)
(which only gives a true or false result)

and
[How to detect duplicate values in PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170807/how-to-detect-duplicate-values-in-php-array)
(which gets what values were duplicated, but not their keys it seems)

I have a need to look through the array and determine any duplicates for repeating to the end-user, including the array keys, so that I can echo those keys as "excel line numbers"

Sample Excel Spreadsheet:

```
E123456
E234567
E345678
E123456
E456789
E111111
E123456
E234567
E333333
E444444
```

Desired Result for end user:

```
E123456 was a duplicate, found on lines 1, 4, and 7
E234567 was a duplicate, found on lines 2 and 8
```

So I need to store both what value got duplicated AND the keys it was duplicated on.

I realize that this would be some combination of array_unique, array_diff, array_keys (and maybe a couple others), but I'm not sure what order to "stack" the calls in to get the desired result, without ending up with some brute-force method that causes the system to choke (the file size is potentially hundreds of lines)

Comment: You will not choke a system with a few hundred items. Have you looked at this: https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/identifying-duplicate-values-in-an-excel-list

Comment: iterate over your rows and fillan array where the key is the value you want to have unique and the value a list of the lines where it occurs.

Comment: @Eriks Klotins thanks, but I know it can be done in excel; the problem is, I have no control over whether the person who uploads that file bothers to do that beforehand :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_count_values function to get amount of each value in the source array and then save only items that occurred more than once. Now array_keys with a 2nd argument returns keys of the array with that value

```
// find duplicates. They will be keys of the array
$res = array_count_values($arr);
$res = array_filter($res, function($x) { return $x > 1;});
// find indexes corresponding that duplicates values
foreach($res as $k=>&$v) {
   $v = array_keys($arr, $k, true);    
}
print_r($res);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7061e57ec66a164ff546b436047c0a110f9dd06e)