# trying to have one choice selected in each drop down

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have a table created in html/php. In the left most cells I have to have a dropdown with various colors. My question is how do I make It so that when a user selects a color in the dropdown, and they try to select It in another one It will not allow them to choose the same color. I also have to alert the user in a non-intrusive way that no color can be chosen more than once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Color Coordinate Generation</h1>
    <?php
      $rowcol = $_GET["rowcol"];
      
      $numColor = $_GET["numColor"];
      
      echo "<table style='width:80%'>";
      
      for($i = 0; $i < $numColor; $i++) {
      
        echo "
      
          <tr>
      
          <td style = 'width: 20%'><label for='color'></label>";
      
      ?>
    <select name="color" id="color">
      <option value='red'>Red</option>
      <option value='orange'>Orange</option>
      <option value='yellow'>Yellow</option>
      <option value='green'>Green</option>
      <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
      <option value='purple'>Purple</option>
      <option value='grey'>Grey</option>
      <option value='brown'>Brown</option>
      <option value='black'>Black</option>
      <option value='teal'>Teal</option>
    </select>
    <?php
      echo "</td>
      
      <td style = 'width: 80%'> hi</td>
      
      </tr>";
      
      }
      
      echo "
      
      </table>";
      
      ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php
      $alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
      
      echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
      
      echo "<td> </td>";
      
      for($i = 0; $i < $rowcol; $i++) {
      
      echo "
      
      <td style = 'width: 2%'>";
      
      echo $alphabet[$i];
      
      }
      
      echo "</td>";
      
      for($i = 1; $i <= $rowcol; $i++) {
      
      echo "<tr>
      
      <td style = 'width: 2%'>";
      
      echo $i;
      
      }
      
      echo "</td></tr>";
      
      ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `how do I make It so that when a user selects a color in the dropdown, and they try to select It in another one` ...did you forget to finish this sentence?

Comment: I think It got deleted in an edit. but I finished the sentence! thank you

Comment: Ok thanks. The answer is "use javascript to check the contents of each dropdown whenever one of them changes, and make sure the values don't match"

Answer (score 0):

PHP should not (and cannot) be involved in users interactions with their browsers. When someone selects a color from a drop-down, it is JavaScript's duty to remove the chosen element from other drop-downs. It's a straight-forward JS code and you should be able to write it with a little search.

There remains the matter of validating the form after submission (if there's any). That's when PHP should play its role. First of all you have to change the `name` attribute of the `select` element to `colors[]`, so PHP would be given the selected results in an array. Then you should check for duplicate values inside the array ([also very straight-forward code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170807/how-to-detect-duplicate-values-in-php-array)), if there were any duplicates, throw an exception and inform the user, if not, then you're good to go.

Hope it can show you the right path to solve your problem.

<sub>P.S: Boy! Haven't seen such code in a long time!</sub>