# compare two arrays and perform some action based on its value php

Tags: php

I just want to know that is there any simplest way to achieve the requirements below?

I Have 2 arrays

```
ARRAY1=[ "1","5","3","4"]
```

and

```
 ARRAY2=[ "1","1","5","5","3","4"]
```

firstly I want to check is `ARRAY2` contains all the values in `ARRAY1`.
i used `array_unque` and the `diff` which is working fine.

So now I want to also check is **every** **values** in `ARRAY1` is repeat morethan **one** in `array2` if it does return true..

How can I achieve this.. Iam a beginner.. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? While we're glad to help when you're stuck, you're still expected to make an effort of your own to try and solve the problem. Start with a simple foreach loop and slowly build your way towards something.

Comment: You could use [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get the frequence of the values in array 2 and compare with the values of array 1

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170807/how-to-detect-duplicate-values-in-php-array

Comment: Side note: you don't need `array_unique` to determine whether it contains all the elements, `array_diff` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = ["1","5","3","4"];
$array2 = ["1","1","5","5","3","3","4","4","7"]; // every value from array 1 is repeated


$array3 = sizeof(array_diff($array1, array_values(array_diff_key($array2, array_unique($array2))) )) > 0 ? false : true;
```

Link : https://3v4l.org/InJb6

Comment: This will fail is `$array2` has a non-duplicate value that isn't inside `$array1`. The requirement is _"So now I want to also check is every values in ARRAY1 is repeat morethan one in array2"_...

Comment: you said in your question that you have done first part of question, please update your question then

Comment: 1) It's not my question. 2) The first step doesn't affect this. Your code will independently fail when there is a single value that's not present in `$array1`.

Comment: Here's what I'm talking about: https://3v4l.org/qm5hH

Comment: It's ok now, but I would include at least a short explanation of how it works, so that any future readers can learn from it.